# Ambiguous use of "??"

Tags: swift

I have a couple of lines of working code:

```
    let email = User.sharedInstance.emailAddress ?? ""
    accountEmailAddress.text = email
```

`User.sharedInstance` is a non-optional instance of the `User` class. Its `emailAddress` property is an optional `String?`. `accountEmailAddress` is a UILabel.

If I try to turn this into a single line of code:

```
    accountEmailAddress.text = User.sharedInstance.emailAddress ?? ""
```

I get the Swift compiler error "Ambiguous use of '??'".

I can't quite figure out what's ambiguous about the use of the nil coalescing operator here. I'm looking to find out why the compiler's complaining, and, out of curiosity, if there's a way of making this a clean one-liner.

(Xcode 6 beta 6.)

Edit: Minimal reproduction in a playground:

```
// Playground - noun: a place where people can play
var foo: String?
var test: String?

// "Ambiguous use of '??'"
foo = test ?? "ValueIfNil"
```

Comment: I guess it is caused by one operand is `NSString` and other one is `String` so it can't figure out the return value.

Comment: Both `UILabel.text` and `User.emailAddress` are `String`s.

Comment: Hmm, `label.text = Optional("maybe") ?? "sure"` works for me...

Comment: I think it may be because of the optionality of accountEmailAddress.text, oddly: If I change the one-liner to assign to `accountEmailAddress.text!` then it doesn't complain...

Comment: @BryanChen They're the same operand types in both the one-liner and the two-liner that works, aren't they?

Comment: @MattGibson `label.text! =` will crash at run-time.

Comment: @akashivskyy Will it? Seems to be working fine right here...

Comment: I've added a minimal reproduction that shows the error in a playground.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I guess this is because of the optionality of `UILabel.text`. Operator `??` has 2 overloads – one returns `T` and the other returns `T?`.

Since `UILabel.text` accepts both `String` and `String?`, compiler cannot decide which overload to use, thus throwing an error.

You can fix this error by strictly specifying the result type:

```
String(User.sharedInstance.emailAddress ?? "")

(User.sharedInstance.emailAddress ?? "") as String

// or, when String! will become String? in the next beta/gm

(User.sharedInstance.emailAddress ?? "") as String?
```

---

Nevertheless, the compiler should automatically prefer non-optional types in this kind of situations, so I suggest filing a bug report on this.

Comment: Thanks, that certainly explains what's going on. I'll throw a bug report Apple's way.

Comment: Apple just notified me that this one is fixed in beta 7, and I've just confirmed that it is. Turns out all I really needed to do was to wait a day. Hindsight is wonderful!